# How Can i Fix This embed message in discord.js. i used command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

here is the code =

I used Command Handler I don't know why it's happening. I am new at coding

if anyone can help me and please quick

please fix this error. or help me to fix this error

**tst.js =**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'tst',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)
        .setDescription("testcmd")
        .setColor("#3535353")
        .addField("Usuario", '${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}')
        .addField("ID", message.author.id)
        .addField("JunayedRafi", message.author.createdAt);
    
    message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

**index.js =**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
 
const prefix = '-';
 
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Muricraft is online!');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else {
        if(command === 'tst'){
            client.commands.get('tst').execute(client, message, args, Discord)

        }
        
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

**here is the error = (if I type -tst in discord this error brings up**

```
PS E:\SOFTOWER INFO\Discord bot\Muricraft> node .
Muricraft is online!
E:\SOFTOWER INFO\Discord bot\Muricraft\commands\tst.js:5
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                      ^

TypeError: Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor
```

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Was about to ask the same thing.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Mohan new version of discord.js

Comment: @JunayedRafi Your code should work fine if you're on v12.

Answer (score 0):

You first need import the `Discord` package before use `MessageEmbed()`.
Then, your script should start like it

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'tst',
  
//The rest of the code
```

Or only call the `MessageEmbed` constructor like this

```js
const { MessageEmbed: Embed } = require('discord.js'); //Embed is the name of variable
module.exports = {
    name: 'tst',
  
//The rest of the code
```

With the last option, you can create a new embed like this example

```js
const embed = new Embed().setDescription("Hello World");
```

I hope I've helped :)